# Bulk delete ec2 snapshots from Jenkins

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, snapshot, aws-cli, deleting

**Use case:**
Export list of snapshots in txt file (old_snapshots.txt) to S3 bucket. From Jenkins, use aws cp command copy file to Jenkins /tmp/directory

```
--dry-run did not show any error
```

However, when passed the following bash line with aws delete command in Jenkins it shows SUCCESS, at the same says error has occurred and the snapshots are not deleted.

```
## actual deletion
        file="/tmp/old_snapshots.txt"
         while read delete_data
         do
        aws ec2 --region eu-west-1 delete-snapshot --snapshot-id $file
        echo "Deleting snapshot $delete_data"
        done <"$file"
```

Output

```
An error occurred (InvalidParameterValue) when calling the DeleteSnapshot operation: Value (/tmp/old_snapshots.txt) for parameter snapshotId is invalid. Expected: 'snap-...'.
Deleting snapshot snap-xxxx81xxxxxx7fxxx

An error occurred (InvalidParameterValue) when calling the DeleteSnapshot operation: Value (/tmp/old_snapshots.txt) for parameter snapshotId is invalid. Expected: 'snap-...'.
Deleting snapshot snap-xxxacc49xxxxxxc26


An error occurred (InvalidParameterValue) when calling the DeleteSnapshot operation: Value (/tmp/old_snapshots.txt) for parameter snapshotId is invalid. Expected: 'snap-...'.
Deleting snapshot snap-04xxxxxxxx3fa3cxxxxxxf4

[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```

**Request:** This error `An error occurred (InvalidParameterValue) when calling the DeleteSnapshot operation`seems too generic? Have anyone experienced seem issue? Also, I did a manual test of deleting just a single snapshot with aws cli by manually adding the snapshot id in Jenkins and that works fine. Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

#### Including aws command

```
aws ec2 --region eu-west-1 delete-snapshot --snapshot-id snap-01x1618xxxxxxa51x
Found snapshotid: snap-01x1618xxxxxxa51x in the uploaded file: /tmp/old_snapshots.txt
Now deleting snapshot id snap-01x1618xxxxxxa51x
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the benefit of other community users, I used the `--debug` flag to discover that additional character `'\r'` were being added to the **snap-#**

**Debug output**

```
2020-01-28 18:09:02,295 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event load-cli-arg.ec2.delete-snapshot.snapshot-id: calling handler <awscli.paramfile.URIArgumentHandler object at >
2020-01-28 18:09:02,296 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event process-cli-arg.ec2.delete-snapshot: calling handler <awscli.argprocess.ParamShorthandParser object at >
2020-01-28 18:09:02,296 - MainThread - awscli.arguments - DEBUG - Unpacked value of u'snap-0xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\r' for parameter "snapshot_id": u'snap-0xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\r'
```

To solve the issue: I passed `tr -d '\r'` to variable holding the value, to make the conversation.

**Example**:

```
tr -d '\r' < input > output
```

**Updated script**

```
file="/tmp/old_snapshots.txt"
cat $file | tr -d '\r' | while read -r line; 
do 
aws ec2 --region eu-west-1 delete-snapshot --snapshot-id $line                        
done
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your script a bit.

```
$ sh abc.sh

What is in delete_data snap-xxxx81xxxxxx7fxxx
What is in file /tmp/old_snapshots.txt
Deleting snapshot snap-xxxx81xxxxxx7fxxx
What is in delete_data snap-xxxacc49xxxxxxc26
What is in file /tmp/old_snapshots.txt
Deleting snapshot snap-xxxacc49xxxxxxc26
What is in delete_data snap-04xxxxxxxx3fa3cxxxxxxf4
What is in file /tmp/old_snapshots.txt
Deleting snapshot snap-04xxxxxxxx3fa3cxxxxxxf4

$ cat abc.sh
## actual deletion

    file="/tmp/old_snapshots.txt"
    while read delete_data
    do
    #aws ec2 --region eu-west-1 delete-snapshot --snapshot-id $file
    echo "What is in delete_data $delete_data"
    echo "What is in file $file"
    echo "Deleting snapshot $delete_data"
    done < $file
```

Your script is calling `file` variable is constant but you need to pass content of file line by line.
So, replace below

```
aws ec2 --region eu-west-1 delete-snapshot --snapshot-id $file
```

With

```
aws ec2 --region eu-west-1 delete-snapshot --snapshot-id $delete_data
```

Comment: @askyagi, thanks a lot for all the effort scanning through the code. Yes, I tested both with the `file` variable and `delete_data` and the result is still the same. The txt file contains only the list of snapshot-ids in a list format.

Comment: Can you update question what value is passed with aws command just echo `aws <parameters>` in script it will give us more idea.